# Random Image change to random element

Tags: jquery

I have a page that randomly changes an image when clicked. It's probably best to have a look at this demo that works fine: http://jahyland.com/demos/ballistic/v1g/

Now I've been asked that along with changing the image when clicked on, clicking the logo will  randomly select one image to randomly change. Yes, confusing.

So I have several arrays with all the various image options:

```
var boyhairhat =   ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg','6.jpg'];
var boychin = ['1.png','2.png','3.png','4.png','5.png','6.png'];
var boymouth = ['1.png','2.png','3.png','4.png','5.png','6.png'];
```

etc... Then an array with all the list of arrays:

```
var randombit = ['boyhairhat','boychin','boymouth'];
```

And then the following functions to try and get the random element changed from the logo click:

```
function randomSelection() {
    return randombit[Math.floor(Math.random() * randombit.length)];
}

$.fn.randomImage = function(selection){
    $(this).click(function(){
        var cur = $('#'+selection+' img').attr('src');
        var rnd = cur;
        while(cur==rnd){
            rnd = 'selection' + selection[Math.floor(Math.random() * selection.length)];
        };
        $('#'+selection+' img').attr('src',rnd).show();
    });
};

$('#logo').randomImage(randomSelection);
```

But needless to say it's not quite working. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use instead:

```
var randombit = [boyhairhat,boychin,boymouth];
```

Comment: Cheers Jakub. I'm sure that's part of the problem, but still isn't wokring for me.

Comment: That was the obvious problem, can you post any error you get?